# Add results of two mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sum

How can I summarize results of two queries below?

```
select   firstname, surname, COUNT(*) as Built 
from     orders 
         join users on orders.builder = users.id 
where    bStop > 1461496211 and bStop < 1461582649 
group by users.id;


select  firstname, surname, COUNT(*) as Built 
from    production_points 
        join users on production_points.rewarded = users.id 
where Date(datetime) = '2016-04-25' 
group by users.id
```

Same user can be in both tables, so i want to sum his results, don't want two separate lines i.e. first one showing 4 and second one 6. Just total 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research as advised by you guys, here is the solution:

```
select uid, firstname, surname, Count(*) as Built from (
select users.id as uid, firstname, surname from orders join users on orders.builder = users.id where bStop > 1461542400 and bStop < 1461592622
union all 
select users.id as uid, firstname, surname from production_points join users on production_points.rewarded = users.id where Date(datetime) ='2016-04-25'
) performance group by uid;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Union. 
If this is mysql you can see its syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

It is similar in the other DB vendors.

Answer (score 1):

Can you maybe get the result of each and assign them to different variables.

And sum up the variables.